# how to add an container in layout using codename one code

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to add layout in a container. It will take the total width of my form, the requirement is to display container in specific coordinates,

```
  FlowLayout flowContainer = new FlowLayout(TextArea.CENTER);
    workersListForm = new Form("test", flowContainer);

    Container container = new Container(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER_ABSOLUTE));

    CommonComponentsForm commonComponentsForm = new CommonComponentsForm();
    Container headerContainer = commonComponentsForm.getHeader();

    Container bodyContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout());
    Container tableBodyContainer = this.getWorkerTableBody();
    Container filterContainer = this.getFilterBody();
    bodyContainer.add(filterContainer);
    bodyContainer.add(tableBodyContainer);

    Container footerContainer = commonComponentsForm.getFooterData();

    container.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, headerContainer);
    container.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, bodyContainer);
    container.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, footerContainer);
    workersListForm.setUIID("workersListForm");
    workersListForm.addComponent(container);
    workersListForm.show();
```

My requirement is to display total layout in centre, without using padding for layout, because I would like to display layout centre in landscape mode and display total screen in portrait mode, like the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hi take a look at this section

http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---positioning-components-using-layout-managers.html

and to display at some specific co-ordinate

http://codenameone.blogspot.co.nz/2009/10/coordinating-that-layout.html

generally to set components in center I do as below:

`Layout1 (LayoutType: border_layout)
|
|-- Layout2 (LayoutType: box_layout_Y and set it in center of Layout1)
     |
     |--Layout3 (LayoutType: box_ly_X or FlowLayout with setAlign CENTER)
     |    (this is first row of components)
     |
     |--Layout4 (LayoutType: box_ly_X or FlowLayout with setAlign CENTER)
     |     (this is second row of components)`

hope it may help you.

Cheers.

Comment: There is also an option to use BorderLayout with absolute center mode depending on the exact requirements. I think the layout gallery is probably the best reference here: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/layouts/package-summary.html as well as the developer guide basics section https://www.codenameone.com/manual/basics.html